# How to perform selectByValue for a dropdown with few headers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Usually I had to deal with drop-down with no headers/headlines, so I just performed them like this:

```
val selectDocTypeDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("admin-select-page")))
selectDocTypeDropDown.selectByValue("245")
```

But now I need to deal with a drop-down with headers, its HTML/CSS is looking like this:

[image]

But it doesn't accept the two lines I did above. What should I do here to select by value?

Comment: Please post the HTML as text and not a picture. Some time in the future the picture will no longer be available and the question will be less useful.

Comment: what exactly error do you get. and, what is language you use?

Comment: I think your question is just duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045183/firefox-phantomjs-login-to-website-not-working/33048616#33048616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// find the select 
val selectDocTypeDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("admin-select-page"))

// find the option to be selected
val optionToSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='admin-select-page']//option[@value='245']"))

selectDocTypeDropDown.click()
optionToSelect.click()
```

I prefer to find the select and the option to be selected together because clicking on the select and then finding the options may sometimes lead to the select box losing focus.